# Too many rows are inserted into Audit Table by Triggers I created

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I want to create history records in table "SampleTableAudit" for all insert, update and delete transactions that happen to records on table "SampleTable"

This would work fine if I had not the need of a trigger that adds a UniqueIdentifier for each inserted record on "SampleTable".

The updates made by the Trigger that updates every new record after being inserted in SampleTable with a new UniqueIdentifier "SampleTableUID" should not be stored for each executed step of the trigger into the "SampleTableAudit" just the final new record including the UniqieIdentifier. At the moment all 3 steps are triggering to insert mechanism.

```
CREATE TABLE "SampleTable" (
"SampleTableID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
"SampleTableUID" nvarchar,
"Name" nvarchar(50),
"City" nvarchar,
"DateCreated" datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
"DateModified" datetime,
"UserNameID" integer
);

CREATE TABLE "SampleTableAudit" (
"SampleTableAuditID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
"SampleTableID" integer,
"SampleTableUID" nvarchar,
"Name" nvarchar(50),
"City" nvarchar,
"DateCreated" datetime,
"DateModified" datetime,
"UserNameID" integer
);

CREATE TABLE "UserName" (
"UserNameID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
"SampleTableUID" nvarchar,
"UserName" nvarchar,
"FullName" nvarchar
);

CREATE TRIGGER "UID"
AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE "SampleTable"
SET "SampleTableUID" = (SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v))
WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid();
END;

CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedUPDATE"
AFTER UPDATE ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID",)
values  (old.SampleTableID,old.SampleTableUID,old.Name,old.City,"update",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,old.UserNameID);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedINSERT"
AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID",)
values  (new.SampleTableID,new.SampleTableUID,new.Name,new.City,"insert",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,new.UserNameID);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedDELETE"
BEFORE DELETE ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID",)
values  (old.SampleTableID,old.SampleTableUID,old.Name,old.City,"delete",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,old.UserNameID);
END;

INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("Russel","Dallas");
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("Jones","Seattle");
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("McIver","San Diego");
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("Mendez","Boston");
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("Roberts","Miami");
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name", "City") VALUES ("Yong","New York");

UPDATE "SampleTable" SET City = 'New York' WHERE Name = "Roberts";

DELETE FROM "SampleTable" WHERE SampleTableID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modifiedUPDATE` trigger should not run for the UPDATE that sets the unique ID.
To prevent it from running, add a [WHEN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that checks for that case (`WHEN OLD.SampleTableUID IS NOT NULL`).

The `modifiedINSERT` trigger does not see the new unique ID in its `NEW` values, so this is the wrong place to add the history record.
Instead, you want to add this history record when the new ID has been set.
Therefore, add an UPDATE trigger with the opposite check in the WHEN clause.

Note: using `last_insert_rowid()` in an INSERT trigger is dangerous; just use `NEW.rowid`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your proposal as following and the results were:

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER "UID"
AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE "SampleTable"
SET "SampleTableUID" = (SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v))
WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid();
END;
>>>> The SampleTableUID was updated but the record was inserted in the SampleTableAudit without the SampleTableUID value

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedDELETE"
BEFORE DELETE ON "SampleTable"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID")
values  (old.SampleTableID,old.SampleTableUID,old.Name,old.City,"delete",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,old.UserNameID);
END;
>>>>>>  Worked fine and all data was inserted into the SampleTableAudit

Comment: >>>>>>UPDATE "SampleTable" SET City = 'New York' WHERE Name = "Jones";

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedUPDATE"
AFTER UPDATE ON "SampleTable"
WHEN OLD.SampleTableUID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID")
values  (old.SampleTableID,new.SampleTableUID,old.Name,old.City,"update",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,old.UserNameID);
END;

Comment: >>>>> The update statement (see directly above) worked fine and made the updates and inserted all data correctly in SampleTableAudit.

Comment: >>>>> It seems that just the insert is not working correctly

CREATE TRIGGER "modifiedINSERT"
AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable"
WHEN NEW.SampleTableUID IS NULL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO  SampleTableAudit ("SampleTableID","SampleTableUID","Name","City","ModifiedType","DateModified","UserNameID")
values  (new.SampleTableID,new.SampleTableUID,new.Name,new.City,"insert",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,new.UserNameID);
END;